# PNG image in iPhone safari is rendering with rasterization issues

Tags: html, ios, png, mobile-safari, raster

We have a transparent background PNG that renders fine in most browsers. It even renders fine in iOS safari on occasion. But many times in iOS safari, when the size of the image (width: 100% in the div) changes dynamically, the image then displays with severe raster issues, as shown in the image.

Has anyone seen this and is there a way to address it?

[shows raster issues in the image as seen on iOS safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVsv3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This really doesn't address the fundamental problem, but I ended up loading the image as base64 data as opposed to from a URL.  This seemed to cure the behavior I was getting.